# Check any two object in an array are Equal using multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

In my angular project i have a DataSource like

```
  [
    {id: "1", name: "John", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"},
    {id: "2", name: "Smith", age: "24", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"},
    {id: "3", name: "Jeff", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ronald", age: "25", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"},
    {id: "5", name: "Ronak", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}
]
```

I need to check if any two or more lines of data are same or not based on multiple conditions. Eg : If any two lines have same age and gender and Role then return their Names

So the Expected Output will be

```
[John,Jeff, Ronak]
```

Since they share the same age, gender and Role
else

```
[]
```

I tried to group the array, but I didn't find any solution to group it using multiple conditions, then tried nested loops, but seems inefficient and the results were not as expected.

Comment: Two things: Can you show us what you've tried?  And if there are multiple groups (say Ronald, like Smith, was 24), what is the expected output?

Comment: What I Did was Using 2 For loops and Comparing values using index, and the above is a dummy model which is created only for the purpose of asking the question. What I needed to identify object having same values and in real application multiple groups are not expected.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that part of the expectation here is to demonstrate your own attempt in the question.  It's not always easy to do so, especially when you're simplifying the data to make a minimal example.  But it does two things: it makes it easier for readers to understand what you want and what didn't work, and it makes it quite possible that you'll find the answer on your own.

Comment: "in real application multiple groups are not expected" does not answer the coding question of what to do if they're found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a joined key for the wanted properties, collenct the names for the group and return all names who are in a group with three or more items.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", name: "John", age: "23", gender: "M", Role: "Student" }, { id: "2", name: "Smith", age: "24", gender: "M", Role: "Teacher" }, { id: "3",  name: "Jeff", age: "23", gender: "M", Role: "Student" }, { id: "4", name: "Ronald", age: "25", gender: "M", Role: "Teacher" }, { id: "5", name: "Ronak", age: "23", gender: "M", Role: "Student" }],
    keys = ['age', 'gender', 'Role'],
    groups = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(o.name);
        return r;
    } , {}),
    result = Object.values(groups).flatMap(a => a.length >= 3 ? a : []);

console.log(result);
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Even though  I get what I needed in the Groups, when I tried flatMap or the last line I get an error 'flatMap does not exist on type unknown[]' , So whats that last line exactly meant ?

Comment: it looks liken, you don't have `flatMap`. if you expect only a single array, you could `find` the array instead.

Comment: Will try that One, but if you don't mind can u explain me how this code find the match as i am new with typescript and these array operations not able to understand properly.

Comment: you can take a look to the object with the combined values and from this object only the values with more than two elements are taken.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper function to group the data appropriately, and pass it a function that generates a unique key from the important data.  Something like this:

```js
// Utility functions
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ({... a, [fn(x)]: [... (a [fn (x)] || []), x]}), {})

const getProp = (obj) => (prop) =>
  obj [prop]

// Helper function
const makeKey = (props) => (record) =>
  props .map (getProp (record)) .join('|')

// Main function
const multipleMatch = (props) => (data) => 
  Object 
    .values (groupBy (makeKey(props)) (data)) 
    .filter (arr => arr.length > 1)

// Demos
const data = [{id: "1", name: "John", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}, {id: "2", name: "Smith", age: "24", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"}, {id: "3", name: "Jeff", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}, {id: "4", name: "Ronald", age: "25", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"}, {id: "5", name: "Ronak", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}]
console .log (multipleMatch (['age', 'gender', 'Role']) (data))

// Changing the age of one to get two different shared groups
const data2 = [{id: "1", name: "John", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}, {id: "2", name: "Smith", age: "24", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"}, {id: "3", name: "Jeff", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}, {id: "4", name: "Ronald", age: "24", gender:"M", Role: "Teacher"}, {id: "5", name: "Ronak", age: "23", gender:"M", Role: "Student"}]
console .log (multipleMatch (['age', 'gender', 'Role']) (data2))
```

The `makeKey` and `getProp` functions could easily be inlined.  But breaking out `groupBy` seems to make the problems much clearer.

This returns an array of arrays of objects.  If you want just their names, it's easy to tack on `.map (group => group .map (record => record .name))`, or, replacing that initial `.map` with `.flatMap`, you get a single array at the cost of losing the potential for reporting on multiple groups.